# Checking to see if the current time is close to 9PM

Tags: c++, time

I want to check if the current time is "close" to 9pm UTC. I have the following code to a.) get "now" and convert it to UTC time and b.)  get 9pm utc time.

Based off when I run it, it looks like it's running. However, I usually use scripting languages, and this looks absolutely crazy to me. I don't necessarily want to shorten this in terms of LOC, but I just wanted to check I'm not violating some principle I don't even know about.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

int main() {
    
    // Get the current time in the machine's local time zone
    std::time_t currentTime = std::time(nullptr);

    // Get the time zone difference between local time and UTC (in seconds)
    std::tm* localTime = std::localtime(&currentTime);
    long localTimeZoneOffset = localTime->tm_gmtoff;

    // Adjust the current time to UTC
    std::time_t nowUtcTime = currentTime - localTimeZoneOffset;
    std::tm* utcLocalTime = std::localtime(&nowUtcTime);
    
    // construct 9pm
    std::tm utc9PM = *std::localtime(&nowUtcTime); // deep copy?
    utc9PM.tm_hour = 21; // 9pm utc
    utc9PM.tm_min = 0;
    utc9PM.tm_sec = 0;
    std::time_t ninePmUTC = std::mktime(&utc9PM);

    //ok
    std::cout << "now UTC in seconds since epoch: " << nowUtcTime << std::endl;
    std::cout << "9pm UTC in seconds sinc epoch: " << ninePmUTC << std::endl;
    std::cout << "now in utc calendar time: " << utcLocalTime->tm_hour << ":" << utcLocalTime->tm_min << ":" << utcLocalTime->tm_sec << std::endl;
    std::cout << "9pm utc in calendar time: " << utc9PM.tm_hour <<":" << utc9PM.tm_min <<":" << utc9PM.tm_sec << std::endl;
    
}
```

Comment: That's how you do it in C.

Comment: @MartinYork As I mentioned, C has `gmtime()` in its Standard Library, which returns the UTC time. I would use that instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is already in the Standard Library.  Use `std::chrono::utc_clock` from `<chrono>`, and compute the duration:

```
const auto now = std::chrono::utc_clock::now();
const auto time_of_day = now - std::chrono::floor<std::chrono::days>(now);
```

An extremely crude example:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    constexpr auto nine_pm = std::chrono::hours(21);
    const auto now = std::chrono::utc_clock::now();
    const auto time_of_day = now - std::chrono::floor<std::chrono::days>(now);
    const auto in_minutes = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::minutes>(nine_pm - time_of_day)
        .count();

    if (in_minutes >= 0) {
        std::cout << in_minutes/60 << ':' << in_minutes%60 << " until 21:00 UTC.\n";
    } else {
        const auto minutes_after = -in_minutes;
        std::cout << minutes_after/60 << ':' << minutes_after%60 << " after 21:00 UTC.\n";
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Or if you stick with `<ctime>`, use `gmtime()` to get UTC.

Also, list your headers in alphabetical order, or some other order that’s easy and logical.  This will make it much easier to notice missing or duplicated headers.

Comment: I didn't state this in the question, but I was mistakenly using 9pm utc to stand for 4PM eastern. After the recent daylight savings time this broke :(

Comment: @Taylor Classic XY problem! You want `std::chrono::zoned_time`, then.